# css extra space in div

Tags: css, css-float

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the my pictures div show in the right place

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/sHcjE/) which looks worse the my page bust will give you an idea of what i"m trying to do

here is how it really looks a the [image: top] of the page and at the [image: bottom]`!

as you can see the div "pictures" has space above the pictures inside it and they pictures are pushed out at the bottom making my gradient incorrect.

I can't figure out where the extra space is coming from

**additional**

there is additional space on the right that grows while you expand the browser window until the next picture can fit then it shrinks. how can I make it so it stays at like 10px until the next picture fits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the `div.spacer` at the top of your pictures DIV is clearing the floated `a.home` (the sidebar, if I'm not mistaken). A possible solution would be to put `overflow:hidden` on the pictures DIV.

(Basically, you can control the "scope" of CSS `clear` by using `overflow` to create what is called a "block formatting context". If you apply `overflow:hidden` to the pictures DIV, then `clear:both` elements inside of that DIV cannot clear floats outside of that DIV.)

Comment: That worked ! I added overflow:hidden then I took out  position:relative;
 top:200px; i had those in there to so the div would over lap the logo and nav bar

Comment: @mcgrailm The growing space is a side-effect of you using floats. Floats actually word-wrap just like words in a line of text do, if they can't all fit. I don't know if there's a solution for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have `top: 200px;` in the CSS of your pictures div

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell with the JSFiddle but:

```
div.pictures {
    position:relative;
    top:200px;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    background: rgba(255,255,238, 0.25)    
}
```

Looks like that `top:200px;` rule is adding significant space.

Answer (score 0):

try putting a `<br style="clear:both;" />` at the end of the div!

Comment: They already did. The `div.spacer` has `clear:both` specified in its CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Set `top` in the div.pictures to 0px;. However, it's difficult to tell if this is the result you want using Fiddle.